# Angle bisector problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$, $AY$ is a perpendicular to the bisector $\angle ABC$ and $AX$ is a perpendicular to the bisector of $\angle ACB$. If $AB= 9cm$ , $AC=7cm$ and $BC= 4cm$, then the length of $XY$ is?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do $X,Y$ lie - on the respective bisectors, on $BC$, or elsewhere? Either way, a possibly useful hint is that $\widehat{XAI}=\widehat{C}/2\,$ and $\widehat{YAI}=\widehat{B}/2\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

AX and AY, when both extended, cut the line BC at X’ and Y’ respectively.

Then, it is not that difficult to see that $\triangle BAX \cong \triangle BX’X$. Similarly, we have $\triangle CAY \cong \triangle CY’Y$. The consequences are:-

1) BX’ = BA, a known quantity and similarly, CY’ = CA; and

2) We can apply the midpoint theorem to $\triangle AX’Y’$ to get $XY = \dfrac {X’Y’}{2}$.

XY can then be found by observing that $X’Y’ = BX’ + CY’ – BC$.

Comment: brilliant solution , thank you sir

Comment: @user373141 If it is so, please accept it as an answer by ticking it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB=c$, $AC=b$, $BC=a$, $\measuredangle BAC=\alpha$, $\measuredangle ABC=\beta$, $\measuredangle ACB=\gamma$,

$R$ be a radius of circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$, $S$ be an area of the triangle

and let be our bisectors intersects in the point $O$.

Thus, $$\measuredangle XAY=90^{\circ}-\frac{\beta}{2}+90^{\circ}-\frac{\gamma}{2}-\alpha=180^{\circ}-90^{\circ}-\frac{\alpha}{2}=90^{\circ}-\frac{\alpha}{2}.$$
By law of sines for $\Delta AOC$ we obtain:
$$\frac{AO}{\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}=\frac{b}{\sin\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{2}}$$ or
$$AO=\frac{b\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}{\cos\frac{\beta}{2}}.$$
But $AO$ is a diameter of the circumcircle of $AXOY$, which says
$$XY=AO\sin\measuredangle XAY=\frac{b\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}}{\cos\frac{\beta}{2}}=\frac{2R\sin\beta\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}}{\cos\frac{\beta}{2}}=4R\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}.$$
Now, $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}=\frac{4+7+9}{2}=10$, which says
$$S=\sqrt{10(10-4)(10-7)(10-9)}=6\sqrt5,$$
$$R=\frac{abc}{4S}=\frac{4\cdot7\cdot9}{4\cdot6\sqrt5}=\frac{21}{2\sqrt5}.$$

Now, by law of cosines for $\Delta ABC$ we obtain:
$$\cos\alpha=\frac{7^2+9^2-4^2}{2\cdot7\cdot9}=\frac{19}{21},$$
$$\cos\beta=\frac{4^2+9^2-7^2}{2\cdot4\cdot9}=\frac{2}{3}$$ and
$$\cos\gamma=\frac{4^2+7^2-9^2}{2\cdot4\cdot7}=-\frac{2}{7}.$$
Thus, $$\sin\frac{\beta}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{2}{3}}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt6},$$
$$\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{2}{7}}{2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}$$ and
$$\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{19}{21}}{2}}=2\sqrt{\frac{5}{21}}.$$
Id est,
$$XY=4\cdot\frac{21}{2\sqrt5}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}\cdot2\sqrt{\frac{5}{21}}=6.$$
Done!

Comment: you are  a great person,  always  helpe me ; thank you and god bless you

Comment: @user373141 Good luck!

Comment: I am working now on a solution using sine law and cosine law ;  when i tried to find the magnitude of $\angle C$ using sine law ; i get $73.393$ ; but the right value is $106.6$  , how could that be possible?  Thank you sir and sorry for extra question

Comment: @user373141 Because $\gamma=\arccos\left(-\frac{2}{7}\right)=180^{\circ}-\arccos\frac{2}{7}.$

Answer (score 0):

Extend Ray AX and Ray BY meeting Line BC  at Q and P respectively.

Then AX  = XQ and AY = YP and ∆ ACQ and ∆ ABP are Isosceles.

Hence, CQ = AC = 7 and BP = AB  = 9 and X is midpoint of AQ and Y is midpoint of AP. Also QP  = 12.

Hence, by Midpoint theorem, XY = 6.

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax: https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex